# jquery. Is it acceptable var = var+1?

Tags: jquery

For example input field

```
<input type="text" name="input[]" id="input0" class="input"  value='3' >
```

I do calculations and result for `id="input0"` is based on (previous) value of `id="input0"`

like this (like php)

```
$('#input0').val( parseInt($('#input0').val(),10) + somevar ).change();
```

When tried seems all works. But is coding is good coding? No problems because of such coding?

Edit

I mean because of such coding is result always what I expect.

initial value of `input0` is `3`

`somevar = 4` (for example)

So new value of `input0` I expect 7 (3+4). So `input0 = input0 + somevar`

As far as i tested result is as expected. But is such coding a good practice?

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not take a second parameter like `parseInt()`

Comment: the `.change` at the end should either not be there at all, or be `.change()` if you need to trigger it for other handlers.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, `change()`. Forgot to type.

Comment: If the code works then you should ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
var somevar=15;
$('#input0').val( parseFloat($('#input0').val()) + somevar );
```

Comment: As I understand such coding is "normal" / good practice. Result would always be as expected.

Comment: @user2118559 : yeah, `parseFloat` method takes only one argument and there was no need of `.change` in end so just removed that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use following syntax to avoid multiple access on $('#input0')...

```
$('#input0').val(function(i, text) {
  return parseFloat(text) + somevar;
});
```